# How do have multiline strings for script call in packer

Tags: packer

I'm doing this:

```
{
  "type": "powershell",
  "script": "myscript.ps1 -param1 {{user `aaaa`}} -param2 {{user `bbbb`}} -param3 {{user `cccc`}}"
}
```

I'm adding more params all the time. How do I break this across multiple lines?

I don't want to use a list of env vars because I want the script to explicitly define its params.

I don't want to use hcl because that's still in beta.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself.  Packer does support [multi-line here documents](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration-0-11/syntax.html).  And they are serious about the "The lines of the string and the end marker must not be indented."

So a solution (in HCL) would look like:

```
provisioner "shell-local" {
  inline = [ <<EOF
myscript.ps1 \
-param1 {{user `aaaa`}} \
-param2 {{user `bbbb`}} \
-param3 {{user `cccc`}}
EOF
  ]
}
```

I'd imagine something similar should work in powershell.